# make: *** No rule to make target 'ell/util.c' needed by 'ell/util.lo'

Tags: make, makefile

I need to install ofono, so I cloned [this ofono](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ofono/ofono.git) repository and did `autoreconf -fi` and `./configure` in the directory. But when I am running `make` or `sudo make install` I am encountering the following error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'ell/util.c' needed by 'ell/util.lo' Stop.
Makefile:2093: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked the folders and ell/util.c exists, but ell/util.lo does not. I also tested on another PC and I'm also getting the same error. Are there any dependencies or steps I missed?

Comment: Did `./configure` show any errors?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what was wrong with installing Ofono from deb-packages? The [ofono-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ofono-dev) package with headers is included in *universe* pocket.

Comment: @Pilot6 no, i didn't get any error messages from there

Comment: @N0rbert i haven't tried that one to be honest. i was told to use and compile the source code itself for easier code modifications and stuff. thanks though, i'll have this link bookmarked for future need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ofono-1.31/ell/*util.h* : `util.h` is a link to "ofono-1.31/**..**/ell/ell/**util.h**", i.e. a directory `ell/` outside the ofono-1.31/ directory, like this :

```
/home/name/tmp/
├── ofono-1.31/
├── ell/
```

Download "ell" :

```
cd [folder with ofono]/
git clone https://github.com/bryanperris/ell.git
```

.... and run `./configure && make` in ofono-1.31/ again.

Comment: this did the trick! thank you very much!